# C# DateTime - converting a DateTimeOffset to another TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

When converting a DateTimeOffset to another TimeZone, the OffSet is incorrect.

I've read many articles and experimented for too many hours, but can't see what I'm missing here:

```
// It's June in the UK and we're in British Summer Time, which is 1 hour ahead of UTC (GMT)
var UKoffsetUtc = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

// It's 4pm - declare local time as a DateTimeOffset
var UKdateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 6, 17, 16, 0, 0, UKoffsetUtc);

// Convert to UTC as a date
var utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(UKdateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Get Aus TimeZoneInfo
var AUSTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");

// Check the Aus offset from UTC
var AUSOffset = AUSTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(utc);
Console.WriteLine(AUSOffset); // Output is 10 as expected

// Declare Aus Time as DateTimeOffset
var AUSDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, AUSTimeZone);

// The Aus Offset from UTC is not correct 
Console.WriteLine(AUSDateTimeOffset.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH:mm zzz"));
```

The output is 18 06 2020 01:00 **+01:00**

Aus are 10 hours ahead of UTC (9 hours ahead of GMT) so the date and time are correct, but not the offset.

How can I get the correct offset in AUSDateTimeOffset?

Comment: I think you can derive the DateTimeOffset from the TimeZoneInfo directly, as in `var ausDTO = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(UKdateTimeOffset, "AUS Eastern Standard Time");`. It should give you the same time but a +10 offset (I don't remember whether the `British Summer Time` TimeZone is available in Windows).

Comment: Thanks, however I'm looking for the time with the correct offset, not the offset in isolation (I've already got that in my code example). So how do I get the Aus Local Time which includes the correct offset ie 18 06 2020 01:00 +10:00

Comment: Sorry @Jimi, I'm still getting familiar with all this - you're exactly right. I feel like I have a good handle on Time zones now, but the MS classes and methods aren't exactly intuitive!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create new offset and use it -

```
    // Create new offset for UTC
    var AUSOffset = new DateTimeOffset(utc, TimeSpan.Zero);

    // Declare Aus Time as DateTimeOffset
    var AUSDateTimeOffset = UKdateTimeOffset.ToOffset(AUSTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(AUSOffset));                              
    Console.WriteLine(AUSDateTimeOffset.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH:mm zzz"));
```

***Or:***

Use [`ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netcore-3.1) as suggested by Jimi in the comment!

```
    var finalDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(UKdateTimeOffset, "AUS Eastern Standard Time");
    Console.WriteLine(finalDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH:mm zzz"));
```

Comment: ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId is what I was looking for - hope to remember this in 2 years time when I next have to deal with International times!!

Comment: Both the options work but jimmi's suggestion would help you in that case!

Answer (score 3):

The error is in this part:

```
var AUSDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, AUSTimeZone);
```

In that code, `utc` is a `DateTime`, and thus the resulting `AUSDateTimeOffset` is actually a `DateTime`.  Its `Kind` will be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

The conversion will have been done correctly, and thus you see the correct date and time in the result.  However, the offset is wrong because it is not part of a `DateTime`.  [The documentation about the `zzz` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier) says:

> With `DateTime` values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. It doesn't reflect the value of an instance's `DateTime.Kind` property. For this reason, the "zzz" format specifier is not recommended for use with `DateTime` values.

Thus, the `+01:00` is coming from your local time zone, not from the target time zone.

There are a few ways you could fix this:

- You could make `AUSDateTimeOffset` a `DateTimeOffset` with the correct offset:

  ```
  DateTime AUSDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, AUSTimeZone);
  TimeSpan AUSOffset = AUSTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(utc);
  DateTimeOffset AUSDateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(AUSDateTime, AUSOffset);
  ```
- You could use a UTC-based `DateTimeOffset` instead of a UTC-based `DateTime`:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset utc = UKdateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime();
  DateTimeOffset AUSDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, AUSTimeZone);
  ```
- You could just convert the orignal `DateTimeOffset`, as there's no need to convert to UTC first:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset AUSDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UKdateTimeOffset, AUSTimeZone);
  ```
- As Jimi pointed out in comments, you can even convert without constructing a `TimeZoneInfo` object at all:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset AUSDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(UKdateTimeOffset, "AUS Eastern Standard Time");
  ```

Any of the above will give the same, correct response.

Comment: Separately, note that `DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime` will *already* have `DateTimeKind.Utc`, so the `SpecifyKind` call in your code is extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get around:

```
var fromTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-06-17T16:00:00+01:00");
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");//TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Australia/Sydney");//for Mac
var toTime = fromTime.ToOffset(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(fromTime.UtcDateTime));
Console.Write(toTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")); //2020-06-18T01:00:00+10:00
```